# Javascript: How to mock unknown object structure properties

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a dynamic mock for a javascript object.
I have a react component that receives an object with a dynamic structure (meaning i don't know which properties exist on it beforehand) and each property is either a json with any level of nesting or a function that returns a string.

example object:

```js
const originalObj = {
    prop1: {
        innerProp2: {
            moreProps: () => "some string",
            differentProp: () => "some string 2",
            anotherProp: () => "something else",
        },
        funcAtLevel2: () => "jlk"
    },
    funcAtThisLevel: () => "this returns string too"
}
```

The component renders the strings that it receives from this object and i'm testing other functionality of the component.
in order for the component to render i need the accessors to work, so if my component looks like this:

```js
function MyComp(props: { content: any }) {
  const { content } = props;
  const moreProps = content.prop1.innerProp2.moreProps(); // moreProps = "some hard code string"
  const differentProps = content.prop1.innerProp2.differentProps(); // differentProps = "some hard code string"
  const anotherProp = content.prop1.innerProp2.anotherProp(); // anotherProp = "some hard code string"
  const funcAtLevel2 = content.prop1.funcAtLevel2(); // funcAtLevel2 = "some hard code string"
  const funcAtThisLevel = content.funcAtThisLevel(); // funcAtThisLevel = "some hard code string"

  // other code...

  return (
    <div>
      <span>{moreProps}</span>
      <span>{differentProps}</span>
      {/* more DOM structure here */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I need the accessors to work dynamically.
I managed to get closer with this:

```js
const handler = {
  get(target, prop, receiver) {
    return new Proxy({ [prop]: () => "some hard code string" }, handler);
  },
};
const CompToRender = <MyComp content={new Proxy({}, handler)} />;
```

However I couldn't manage to return the last accessed property as method. How can I implement it?

EDIT: what i'm looking for is the magical object that i can pass to the rendered component instead of the one that is passed in production which will return some hard coded string so the component won't fail to render (the string value is of none importance).

```js
const magicalObj = // how to define this without defining each property explicitely? the "content" object can be very large (over 1000 keys)
const CompToRender = <MyComp content={magicalObj} />;

function MyComp(props: { content: any }) {
  const { content } = props;
  
  // so moreProps and the variables below will receive some string just so the component will render
  // without some accessor the properties will be undefined and it will throw an error
  const moreProps = content.prop1.innerProp2.moreProps(); // moreProps = "some hard code string"
  const differentProps = content.prop1.innerProp2.differentProps(); // differentProps = "some hard code string"
  const anotherProp = content.prop1.innerProp2.anotherProp(); // anotherProp = "some hard code string"
  const funcAtLevel2 = content.prop1.funcAtLevel2(); // funcAtLevel2 = "some hard code string"
  const funcAtThisLevel = content.funcAtThisLevel(); // funcAtThisLevel = "some hard code string"

  // other code...

  return (
    <div>
      <span>{moreProps}</span>
      <span>{differentProps}</span>
      {/* more DOM structure here */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: How does the `MyComp` know which properties to access if they're dynamic? In the code you posted, these look quite hardcoded.

Comment: What kind of test are you writing? Why can't you pass the `originalObj` from your first snippet - that looks like a quite good test sample?

Comment: i'm simplifying it here, but the MyComp comes from an external library and the prop is injected from somewhere else. regardless if that content object has a large amount of properties (could be over 1000 in my case) i don't want to mock them one by one

Comment: So you don't control the data that gets passed into your test? Why are you even testing `MyComp`  from an external library? Not sure what your goal is with the mocking. And what do you mean by "*return the last accessed property as method.*"? Maybe it would be helpful if you [edit]ed the question to include the (non-working) test code that shows how you want to *use* the desired mock.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code will work with this `handler`:

```
const handler = {
  get() {
    const f = () => 'value returned from function';
    Object.setPrototypeOf(f, new Proxy({}, handler));
    return f;
  },
};
```

That is, if you define `const content = new Proxy({}, handler);`, then `content.a.b.c.whatever()` will return `'value returned from function'`.

The key is returning a function that "extends" a `Proxy` using `setPrototypeOf` (I took the idea from [invokable](https://github.com/kourge/invokable/blob/master/index.ts#L85))